# React Datepicker, excluir horarios de una fecha

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Estoy usando esta libreria:

https://reactdatepicker.com/

Existen dos propiedades, excludeDates y excludeTimes, que según le mande fecha u hora, y a cual, excluye una o la otra

La pregunta es para excluir por ejemplo las 17:00 del 10 de diciembre, y que al cambiar al 11 de diciembre, vuelva a estar disponible el 17:00

Aquí un ejemplo de como funcionan las fechas, pero aplica a todos los días :(

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dates'));
var dataNew = new Date(data);
console.log(dataNew);
console.log('Hora:' + dataNew.getHours());
console.log('Minutos:' + dataNew.getMinutes());
var hourGet = dataNew.getHours();
var minuteGet = dataNew.getMinutes();
var c = new Date();
c.setMinutes(minuteGet);
c.setHours(hourGet);
var excludeTimes = c;
console.log('tiempos:' + excludeTimes);

const isWeekday = (date) => {
  var b = new Date(date);
  const day = b.getDay(date);
  return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
};

var minTime = new Date();
minTime.setMinutes(0);
minTime.setHours(17);

var maxTime = new Date();
maxTime.setMinutes(30);
maxTime.setHours(20);

return (
  <DatePicker
    selected={this.state.startDate}
    onChange={this.onClick}
    filterDate={isWeekday}
    placeholderText="Selecciona un día y hora"
    showTimeSelect
    minTime={minTime}
    maxTime={maxTime}
    dateFormat="MMMM d h:mm aa"
    excludeTimes={[excludeTimes]}
    inline
  />
);
```

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor traduce tu pregunta pues estás en SO en español, en caso contrario es seguro termine cerrada

Comment: Gracias, no me di cuenta que estaba en el de español!

Comment: A primera vista, se me hace que deberías condicionar el agregar o no una hora a tu variable `excludeTimes` cuando la fecha sea 10 de diciembre, pero ¿por qué debería ser excluida la hora del 10 de diciembre? ¿qué tiene de especial ese día? creo que te falta algo por explicar en tu problema.

Comment: Porque es para turnos, ponele que alguien reserve esa hora para el turno del 10 de diciembre. Solo ese estaría ocupado, el resto no, a menos que reserven para otro día y así.